# Simple C++ program to add two integers

Tags: c++, beginner

I started learning C++ and the first exercise was to create a small program to add two numbers. No more requirements. I did this and put a small validate the user input. I am sure that it could be much better written, so I appreciate all the critics and suggestions.

```
#include <iostream>

int x;
int sum = 0;
int i = 0;

int addTwoNumbers()
{
    while(i<2)
    {
        std::cin >> x;
        if(std::cin.fail())
        {
           std::cout << "Error! Invalid Input" << std::endl;
           std::cin.clear();
           std::cin.ignore(256,'\n');
        }
        else
        {
             sum += x;
             i++;
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
int main()
{
    std::cout << "Enter two integers" << std::endl;
    return sum = addTwoNumbers();
}
```

Comment: I tried to learn before but didnt get much far. I saw a bit of python and c#

Comment: Incorporating advice from an answer into the question violates the question-and-answer nature of this site.  You could post improved code as a new question, as an answer, or as a link to an external site - as described in [I improved my code based on the reviews. What next?](/help/someone-answers#help-post-body).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Good job on your first program!

Before moving on to the review, a quick note on `using namespace std`

As long as you do it in a cpp file (and not a header), bringing in symbols from a namespace one at a time is absolutely fine, since you are in control:

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;
```

## Errors

**main's return value**

The `main()`'s return value is for program status, not program output. I suspect you meant to do:

```
cout << "the sum is: " << addTwoNumbers() << endl;
return 0;
```

## Good practice improvements

**Avoid globals**

```
int x;
int sum = 0;
int i = 0;
```

These have no business being global variables, they belong inside of your functions, as close to their first use as possible:

```
for(int i=0; i<2;)
{
    int x;
    cin >> x;
```

**istream::fail() vs operator bool()**

**Edit** Disregard this recommendation. See the comment below.

<s>instead of `if(std::cin.fail())` you should simply do `if(std::cin)`, it actually covers more scenarios as well.</s>

**istream::ignore()**

Whenever you use an arbitrary number like 256, it's a sign that something is not how it should be. In this specific case, you want to do `cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n')`

## From a higher level:

**addTwoNumbers() does too many things**

Try to keep your functions short, single-purpose and reusable.

As guidance, look at this version of your `main()`.

```
int main() {
  cout << "Enter two integers" << endl;

  int first = getNumber();
  int second = getNumber();

  cout << "the sum is: " << (first + second) << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

`getNumber()` would now be be a usefull and reusable piece of code, which is what functions should be.

Comment: Using `if (std::cin)` together with a `while` loop can quickly lead to an endless loop. The original code carefully avoids this by only checking for conversion failure.

Comment: @RolandIllig Thanks, I ammended the revierw.

Answer (score 2):

The variables `x`, `sum` and `i` are currently *global variables*. But they are only used in the `addTwoNumbers` function. Therefore they should be declared inside that function. Just move the three lines down after the opening `{`.

The number 256 looks arbitrary to me. Instead of this number, you could read the rest of the line like this:

```
std::string line;
std::getline(std::cin, line);
```

Instead of `std::cout << "some string" << std::endl`, you can just write `std::cout << "some string\n"`. This is faster than your current code.

You currently don't output the result of the calculation. You should do so like this:

```
int sum = addTwoNumbers();
std::cout << "The sum is " << sum << "\n";
```